# AWS S3 download buckets

Tags: amazon-s3

How can I download files from AWS s3 to my local computer. I use mover for scheduling but  I don't find any option to download to hard disk.

Thanks a lot

Ragam

Answer (score 1):

You can use [minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) for the same, its a single binary file. Its open source & supports Linux, Mac, Windows, FreeBSD operating system.

**Installing**

```
GNU/Linux, Download mc for:

64-bit Intel from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc
32-bit Intel from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-386/mc
32-bit ARM from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-arm/mc
$ chmod +x mc
$ ./mc --help

Microsoft Windows, Download mc for:

64-bit from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/windows-amd64/mc.exe
32-bit from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/windows-386/mc.exe
C:\Users\Username\Downloads> mc.exe --help
```

**Setting up**

```
$ ./mc config host add <ALIAS> <YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT> <YOUR-ACCESS-KEY> <YOUR-SECRET-KEY> S3v4
```

*Example*

```
 $ ./mc config host add mys3 https://s3.amazonaws.com BKIKJAA5BMMU2RHO6IBB V7f1CwQqAcwo80UEIJEjc5gVQUSSx5ohQ9GSrr12
```

**Copying from S3 to local machine [Windows]**

Copy a bucket recursively from aliased Amazon S3 cloud storage to local filesystem on Windows.

```
$ ./mc cp --recursive s3\documents\ C:\Backups
```

**Copying from S3 to local machine [Linux]**

Copy a bucket recursively from aliased Amazon S3 cloud storage to local filesystem on Linux.

```
$ ./mc cp --recursive s3/documents/ /home/minio/Backups
```

Note: Here content of bucket "documents" are getting copied locally to Backups directory.

Hope it helps.
Desclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Answer (score 0):

There are many software packages available, most free, that will allow you to do that. I use Cloudberry's products. You can also link to each file directly. Looking at the properties of the files in the AWS console will give you the required information.